# Using the $_COOKIE var to keep important data

Tags: php, cookies, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin. All the functions I'm writing are 'hooked' into certain wordpress events. This means I have a hard time creating variables that I need to use in several functions.

For example:

There's two functions that are hooked in somewhere:

```
Display_if_facebook_connected() { 
   if (Check_facebook_connected()) { return 'Yes, connected!' } 
   return ''; 
} 

Display_if_facebook_connected() { 
   if (!Check_facebook_connected()) { return 'No, not connected!' } 
   return ''; 
}
```

And they both run a very heavy function:

```
Check_facebook_connected() { // some heavy facebook connect stuff, return bool }
```

I'm basically trying to avoid having the heavy function run twice, since it will have the same result.

In this case, would it be safe to do `$_COOKIE['check_facebook_connected'] = true;` and then read that variable in the `Display_if_facebook_connected()`?

By safe I mean that the user can't see or change the value. Since **the cookie is never actually set**, I think/hope it just disappears at the end of the php code.

I wouldn't be surprised if there is some better way, or better var, to do this with, but with my limited understanding of php I can't think of any.

**UPDATE:**
About sessions: I don't need the values to persist over multiple pages, just one page load. Since Wordpress doesn't use sessions I see no reason to change it.

I experimented a bit and the problem persists:

All of the following code is in the main file of my wordpress plugin. The way I understand it, the plugin file is 'included' at every request, so all code is run everytime I refresh my testpost.

Firstly I create the variable:

```
 $myplugin_connected = false;
```

Then I hook my function in the right place:

```
add_shortcode( 'myplugin_notconnected', 'myplugin_notconnected_func' );
```

This basically hooks the `myplugin_notconnected_func()` function into the [myplugin_notconnected] shortcode. *(A **shortcode** is text in a wordpress post, some id between [ ]-brackets. Wordpress loads the code associated with the shortcode whenever it appears.)*

Here's the `myplugin_notconnected_func()`:

```
function myplugin_notconnected_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    echo '<p>connected: ' . var_export($myplugin_connected, true)  . '</p>';
    return '$contents';
}
```

And here's the result:

> connected: NULL

This is why I was trying to use $_COOKIE variables because at least they persist over the whole php instance. I apologize for lack of coherence, I'm learning as I go and I definitely appreciate the help!

Comment: Would a session variable not be better in this instance? I am not familiar with WP plugins - but are there not documented ways to persist plugin data?

Comment: Sessions end by browser close not the cookie, so I guess you need here a session variable to store your data.

Comment: @joon: I guess it could be helpful if you'd clarify for how long you want the connection state to persist.

Comment: WP doesn't use sessions and I was exploring other possibilities before getting into installing sessions on WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scope

Referring to the updated part of your question:

Defining

```
$myplugin_connected = false;
```

and getting `NULL` as result on a subsequent

```
var_export($myplugin_connected, true)
```

could mean, that you either defined `$myplugin_connected` *outside global scope* (e.g. in a function instead of main), or you *have* defined in global scope, but have some `unset($myplugin_connected)` somewhere before the `var_export`. In both cases the return value of `var_export` would be `NULL`.

In your case I believe the former is more probably. You could use:

```
$GLOBALS['myplugin_connected'] = false;
```

and

```
var_export($GLOBALS['myplugin_connected'], true)
```

to have the connection state (which already has been determined once by your "heavy" function before) available in your shortcode handler.

### Cookie

To answer your origin question:

> In this case, would it be safe to do
>   $_COOKIE['check_facebook_connected'] = true; and then read that
>   variable in the Display_if_facebook_connected()?

Well, `$_COOKIE` is a server-side [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), so yes, as long as you never actually send/set that cookie on response, the user wouldn't see, nor could change it.

Personally, using `$_COOKIE` to save a state which is only valid for a single page load, feels just plain wrong to me.

I'd recommend to use at least `$GLOBALS` over `$_COOKIE` - or maybe even better use a [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variable instead of a superglobal in this case - e.g. something like this:

```
function isConnected() {
    static $bConnected = null;
    if ($bConnected === null)
        $bConnected = Check_facebook_connected();
    return $bConnected;
}
```

But that's always in the eye of the beholder^^

Comment: I didn't know $GLOBALS could do that, thank you. Probably wordpress runs the plugins inside their own scope to avoid name collissions...

Answer (score 3):

```
Display_if_facebook_connected() { 
   $result = Check_facebook_connected();
   if (!$result) { return 'No, unconnected!' } else { return 'Yes, connected!' } 
} 


$connected = Display_if_facebook_connected();
```

Comment: Well that looks the answer to me but I still don't get why the OP has a problem.

Comment: he does not have problem, but he was calling Check_facebook_connected(); (heavy function) twice instead of once

Comment: @genesis: I'm not sure, if the OP really wants just different return values (as your solution would do). I think the OP wants to call `Display_if_facebook_connected` multiple times in the same script, but wants the heavy `Check_facebook_connected()` function only be executed *once* at the same time.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what my script does... Owch, wait, I'll edit it

Comment: I had to -1 this. You only need if... else and only two returns. Right now you have `if A then return val1, if not A then return val2, if neither A nor not A then return val3`

Comment: yes because OP had it like this. Edited and it should be fine right now

Comment: Thanks however for noting me reason. There are many downvoters which just downvote and then run away :)

Comment: So, to be clear, this is exactly what I am trying to do, but failing at. I made an update with new findings, hopefully this makes things clearer. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
Check_facebook_connected()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["is_facebook_connected"])) return ($_SESSION["is_facebook_connected"] === true);
    // if we get here we haven't checked the facebook connection status, so do it
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use sessions... I'm not sure if it's worth it for just one variable.